# React.useEffect: Component re-renders with window.location.pathname in dependency array despite warning from ESLint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, eslint

I have a left-side menu that has sub-options which need to be selected/unselected based on the current URL path. In the process of finding a solution for this, I found that the following code gives the ESLint error as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname === "/events/list") {
      setManageEventsOpen(true);
      setSelectedListItem(LIST_SELECTED);
    }
    if (window.location.pathname === "/events/map") {
      setManageEventsOpen(true);
      setSelectedListItem(MAP_SELECTED);
    }
    if (window.location.pathname === "/events/calendar") {
      setManageEventsOpen(true);
      setSelectedListItem(CALENDAR_SELECTED);
    }
  }, [window.location.pathname]);

React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'window.location.pathname'. 
Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. 
Outer scope values like 'window.location.pathname' aren't valid 
dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render 
the component.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

However, when I run this code, I notice that the component DOES re-render when the path changes. I thought this was just because the whole app is reloading when manually changing the URL and refreshing the page, but even using history.push('/events/list') from another component will cause a re-render.

I'm wondering, is this warning incorrect? Anyone see different results?

Note: I've got a better solution for this in my app, but I'm still curious about the warning.

Comment: The re-render is likely being caused by whatever JS routing library you're using, maybe ReactRouter? An external dependency will not cause a React component to re-render, only changes to props and state will do that.

Comment: I do have react router, but since I have window.location.pathname specified in the dependencies list, wouldn't this cause the useEffect to only trigger if that property changed (rather than other props which might be changed by react router?) Also this component is the one which renders the react-router routes, so I'm not sure if the props are actually changing due to this library.. Hm.

Comment: The dependencies list means, "when this component renders, call this function if this value changed since the last render." If `window.location.pathname` changes between renders then your `useEffect` will get called again. However, there is no code "observing" `window.location.pathname`; if it changes your `useEffect` will only get called the next time something else causes your component to render.

Comment: Thanks Ross - this clears up my question I believe!

Answer (score 5):

The fact that your app re-renders when the path changes doesn't mean that the warning is incorrect. It means that your `useEffect` logic is relying on unrelated logic, which is confusing and prone to bugs.

Instead, you should explicitly listen/subscribe to changes to `location.pathname` - so that your component re-renders with the updated value. Given that you use React Router, check out their [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook:

```js
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
  if(location.pathname === "/events/list") {
...
```

Comment: This answer helped me! However, it looks like the link to the docs has changed. Here is the new one: [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)